# Difference between "find ... -exec sort" and "find ... | sort"

Tags: shell

What's the difference between these two commands?

```
find . -name "*.cpp" -exec sort \;
find . -name "*.cpp" |  sort
```

Answer (score 3):

The first command runs `sort` (without an argument) for every file which is found by the criteria specified. This is (as Mat has pointed out in his answer) is quite useless. The  way to get sort to run for every file is to say `find . -name "*.cpp" -exec sort {} \;`. This would be like running `sort a.cpp; sort b/c.cpp; ...` for every file matched.

The second produces a list of `.cpp` files and then pipes *the list* through `sort` producing a sorted list of cpp files.

Comment: I didn't notice that problem in the question. I've edited my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first one runs `sort` without any argument for each `.cpp` file  found. That's pretty useless, sort will be waiting for input on `stdin`.

The second sorts the list of all the `.cpp` filenames.

Answer (score 0):

The first one reads stdin for each of the `*.cpp` files `find` finds and sorts every line you might be feeding it.

The second one sorts the list of the `*.cpp` files `find` finds.